# Android Create Button From Drawable XML

Tags: android, xml, button

I'm wanting to use my formatted button (From XML) programmaticly.

This is my ButtonShape.xml that lives in the drawable folder.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button" />

    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/buttonpressed" />
</selector>
```

This my code for

```
Button newBut;
newBut = new Button(this);  

                newBut.setText("("+breakJobup[0]+") "+breakJobup[1]+" "+breakJobup[2]+" - "+breakJobup[3]+"99999999999999999992");
                newBut.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#404040"));

                newBut.setTag(breakJobup[0]); //hide job id within the button.
                newBut.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
                newBut.setSingleLine();
                newBut.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(50);
                newBut.setSelected(true);
```

any idea on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code.

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(newBut.getContext(), R.drawable.ButtonShape);
ViewCompat.setBackground(newBut, drawable);
```

Comment: Thanks for this.

ContextCompat.
and
ViewCompat

Cannot resolve symbol

Comment: Adds `compile "com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'"` to your dependencies.

Comment: Within build.gradle ?

Comment: Yes, in build.gradle

Comment: Error:Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>

Comment: Follow the instructions in this message or use an older version of support-v4 lib. More info about dependencies you can see in this link:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#dependencies